# Why does my MessageBox.Show generate an error about an argument and overload?

Tags: c#, string, messagebox

```
private void btnKaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(" Sayin " + txtAdi.Text + txtSoyadi.Text
        + "  " + "Kredi Miktari=" + txtMiktar.Text.ToString() + "TL"
        + Environment.NewLine + "Aylik Odeme=" + nmrVade.Value + "TL",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo
        );
}
```

How can I solve this 2 errors ?

> Error  2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'string'    C:\Users\LEVENT\Desktop\bilge adam\week1_day3\WinBatanBank\WinBatanBank\Form1.cs    23  189 WinBatanBank
>
> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string, string)' has some invalid arguments  C:\Users\LEVENT\Desktop\bilge adam\week1_day3\WinBatanBank\WinBatanBank\Form1.cs    23  13  WinBatanBank

Comment: Totally agree but it was my 1st post that's why I couldn't manage it, sorry about that.

Comment: Side note: Don't you think this is more readable **`string msg = String.Format("Sayin {0} {1} Kredi Miktari={2} TL\nAylik Odeme={3} TL", txtAdi.Text, txtSoyadi.Text, txtMiktar.Text, nmrVade.Value);`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`MessageBox.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx) has a relatively large number of overloads but none that take only a `string` and `MessageBoxButtons` as parameters. You can try to use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z.aspx) which takes 2 `strings`, `text` and `caption`, followed by `MessageBoxButtons`:

```
private void btnKaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(
        " Sayin " +txtAdi.Text + txtSoyadi.Text + "  "+ "Kredi Miktari=" + txtMiktar.Text.ToString()+"TL" + Environment.NewLine + "Aylik Odeme=" + nmrVade.Value+"TL", 
        "Some Caption", 
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1 and 2) MessageBox doesn't have an overload for (string, MessageBoxButtons).  You'll need to use the overload for (string Text, string Title, MessageBoxButtons Buttons)

```
MessageBox.Show("Display Text Here", "Box Title Here", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's go over the errors and see what they mean.

> Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'string'

This means the function is expecting a parameter of type `string`, but you supplied a parameter of type `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons`. If it was possible to convert your parameter to a `string`, you wouldn't get this error. So this can be fixed by supplying a `string`.

> Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

This means that your call to the function is incorrect. You could have multiple errors like the first one (where multiple parameters are incorrect), and you'd also get one error like this one. It means that the compiler thinks you want to supply two `string` parameters, but it appears you haven't done so.

In Visual Studio, when you are typing code, you often get a little box with suggestions. This is the IntelliSense feature. If you carefully read the box, you'll see what you need to supply as the next parameter.

Another option is to look at the official documentation. If you search for *msdn messagebox.show* with your favourite search engine, you'll quickly find a link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx
It has a list of *overloads*, that's basically a list of all possible parameter combinations. Look at the name or the description to find the one you want to use, or to find the most similar one to what you're currently trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You've used the wrong amount/combination of arguments.

Try to add a messagebox title:

```
MessageBox.Show( " Sayin " +txtAdi.Text + txtSoyadi.Text + "  "+ "Kredi Miktari=" + txtMiktar.Text.ToString()+"TL" + Environment.NewLine + "Aylik Odeme=" + nmrVade.Value+"TL",
                 "messageBoxTitle",
                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```